# Enumerate years between two dates with calculated values

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, view, generate-series

I have a postgres table that looks something like this:

```
proposal_id | nih_budget_start | nih_budget_end  | nsf_start_date | nsf_end_date   | award_amount
proposal_A  | 03/01/2000       | 12/31/2000      |                |                | 10,000
proposal_B  |                  |                 | 08/01/2005     | 07/31/2009     | 5,000,000
proposal_C  | 06/27/2012       | 11/17/2013      |                |                | 420,000
```

The dates have the `date` data type.

I'd like to create a view that tells me each year the proposal was funded, and what the average award amount was. So, the view might look something like this (option 1):

```
proposal_id | start_year | end_year | average_award
proposal_A  | 2000       | 2000     | 10,000
proposal_B  | 2005       | 2009     | 1,000,000 
proposal_C  | 2012       | 2013     | 210,000
```

Or -- even better -- this (option 2):

```
proposal_id | year | award
proposal_A  | 2000 | 10,000
proposal_B  | 2005 | 1,000,000
proposal_B  | 2006 | 1,000,000
proposal_B  | 2007 | 1,000,000
proposal_B  | 2008 | 1,000,000
proposal_B  | 2009 | 1,000,000
proposal_C  | 2012 | 210,000
proposal_C  | 2023 | 210,000
```

Also, it might be nice to have the award amount prorated for partial-year funding, but this isn't completely necessary.

Based on an answer suggested below, I'm currently doing this, which seems to be working as expected to get option 1 above:

```
CREATE VIEW award_per_year AS
select t1.proposal_id,t1.START_DATE,t1.END_DATE,
(t1.adjusted_award_amount/((t1.END_DATE - t1.START_DATE) + 1.)) avg_award
from
(select t2.proposal_id,
(extract(year from START_DATE)) START_DATE,
(extract(year from END_DATE)) END_DATE,
t2.adjusted_award_amount from
(select proposal_id,
case when nih_budget_start is not NULL then nih_budget_start else nsf_start_date end start_date,
case when nih_budget_end is not NULL then nih_budget_end else nsf_end_date end end_date,
adjusted_award_amount from proposal)t2)t1
```

Comment: Why do you need an array?  Why not just the first year and last year?  or something like that?

Comment: I want to plot the average award amount for each year the proposal was funded. But, I suppose I could do the enumeration of years outside of the database. That would be easier I suppose... Hm.

Comment: Then it would be better I think if you get the years for a proposal as rows rather then a comma separated list, am I right? Please rethink

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1: use [`COALESCE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL)

```
SELECT proposal_id, start_year, end_year
     , award_amount/((end_year - start_year) + 1.0) AS avg_award
FROM  (
   SELECT proposal_id
        , extract(year FROM COALESCE(nih_budget_start, nsf_start_date))::int AS start_year
        , extract(year FROM COALESCE(nih_budget_end, nsf_end_date))::int AS end_year
        , award_amount
   FROM   proposal
   ) sub;
```

Option 2: use [`generate_series()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-srf.html)

```
SELECT proposal_id
     , generate_series(start_year, end_year) AS year
     , award_amount/((end_year - start_year) + 1.0) AS avg_award
FROM  (
   SELECT proposal_id
        , extract(year FROM COALESCE(nih_budget_start, nsf_start_date))::int AS start_year
        , extract(year FROM COALESCE(nih_budget_end, nsf_end_date))::int AS end_year
        , award_amount
   FROM   proposal
   ) sub;
```

[**-> SQLfiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/010fd/3)

Comment: Option 1 works great! Option 2 gives me the following error: `ERROR: function generate_series(double precision, double precision) does not exist`

Comment: @ems: A cast to `integer` was missing. Added the fiddle to demonstrate.

Comment: @ems do a extract(year FROM COALESCE(nih_budget_start, nsf_start_date))::INT is needed

Answer (score 1):

From your clarification it seems it would be better for you to get a list like below:

```
proposal_ID | years_funded  | average_award
proposal_A  | 2000          | 10,000
proposal_B  | 2005          | 1,000,000
proposal_B  | 2006          | 1,000,000
proposal_B  | 2007          | 1,000,000
proposal_B  | 2008          | 1,000,000
proposal_B  | 2009          | 1,000,000
proposal_C  | 2012          | 210,000
proposal_C  | 2013          | 210,000
```

On the front end you can then use this list to display year wise funding of proposal. Please confirm.

Based on your input here is a query which can achieve first output result set you want:

```
SELECT proposal_id,
     TO_CHAR(COALESCE(nih_budget_start, nsf_start_date),'YYYY') AS start_year,
     TO_CHAR(COALESCE(nih_budget_end, nsf_end_date),'YYYY') AS end_year,
     award_amount/(TO_CHAR(COALESCE(nih_budget_end, nsf_end_date),'YYYY')::INT - TO_CHAR(COALESCE(nih_budget_start, nsf_start_date),'YYYY')::INT+1) AS average_award
FROM Proposals
```

Following query can achieve the second result set you need using recursive CTE:

```
WITH RECURSIVE dates AS
( 
     SELECT proposal_id,nih_budget_start,nsf_start_date,nih_budget_end,nsf_end_date, TO_CHAR(COALESCE(nih_budget_start, nsf_start_date),'YYYY')::INT  AS Dt,
     award_amount/(TO_CHAR(COALESCE(nih_budget_end, nsf_end_date),'YYYY')::INT - TO_CHAR(COALESCE(nih_budget_start, nsf_start_date),'YYYY')::INT+1) AS average_award
     FROM proposals
     UNION ALL
     SELECT proposal_id,nih_budget_start,nsf_start_date,nih_budget_end,nsf_end_date, d1.dt + 1, average_award FROM dates d1
     WHERE d1.dt < TO_CHAR(COALESCE(nih_budget_end, nsf_end_date),'YYYY')::INT 
 )
SELECT proposal_id, dt AS year, average_award  FROM dates d ORDER BY proposal_id,dt
```

See the code at [**SQLFiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5e144/22)

Comment: Yep. This would be fine. I updated my question to reflect this option also. Thanks!

Comment: Ok Gr8, I will try to give you solution soon

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```
select t1.proposal_ID,t1.START_DATE,t1.END_DATE,
DIV(t1.award,(t1.END_DATE - t1.START_DATE + 1))award
from
(select t2.proposal_ID,
(substr(t2.START_DATE,7,4)::integer) START_DATE,
(substr(t2.END_DATE,7,4)::integer) END_DATE,
t2.award from
(select proposal_ID,
case when length(start_date1) = 10 then start_date1 else start_date2 end start_date,
case when length(end_date1) = 10 then end_date1 else end_date2 end end_date,
award from table1)t2)t1;
```

### [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e37db/1)

Comment: This looks plausible, but it's not working because my dates have the `date` datatype. The 'NaN' values are just missing, not the string 'NaN'. So, I think I should be able to use `extract(year from START_DATE)` to get the years, though I'm not sure what will happen with this for missing values.